# Alternate boot on Lenovo Thinkbook Ultrabook

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, laptop, thinkpad

My wife's Aunt's friend's brother's passed away, and I am charged with getting into his computer. It's a Lenovo Thinkpad Ultraboot; he set a password onto boot-up screen, and of course no one knows what the password is.

The manual says to press F12 repeatedly while it boots, but that has no effect. I also tried just holding F12 while it booted, that also had no effect. I have also tried repeatedly pressing F1, F2, Fn-F1, Fn-F2, and F12, and none of them produce another boot menu.

Can someone tell me how to boot, once I've got an external CD for the recovery CD I made with another machine?

Comment: To clarify, is this a BIOS level password or a disk level password?

Comment: The password being requested is on what I think of as a Windows Logon Screen -- so it isn't BIOS or disk, it's the OS.

Comment: use a linux live CD/DVD to boot into a linux desktop, then access the hard drive .... hopefully the drive is not encrypted

Comment: Well, what I'm asking is how to boot from a CD -- there's supposed to be a menu for boot options that you get by pressing some key while powering the machine, and the ones I've been told don't work.